# Replace shared_ptr object with another one

Tags: c++, object, replace, shared-ptr

Basically I have base class `Employee` with `enum class` inside it, and derived classes `Worker`, `Intern`, `Manager` with specified field from `enum` describing them.

```
class Employee {
public:
    enum class Status {
        Intern,
        Worker,
        Manager
    };
protected:

    int employeeID;
    std::string Name;
    std::string Surname;
    int Salary;
    bool Hired;
...
}

class Worker : public Employee {

protected:

    Status status = Status::Worker;
}

// "Intern" and "Manager" same way.
```

I store objects in `vector<shared_ptr<Employee>> Firm;` and modifying them via `sourceEmployee[index]` reference.

What I want to do is:

Promote/demote employee, how? I want to look for specified employee and check his status. If it's `Worker` I want to delete `Worker class` object and make object `Manager` instead, with all fields saved from `Worker` like: name, surname etc.

My prototype (does not working) looks like that:

```
    auto it = std::find_if(sourceEmployee.begin(), sourceEmployee.end(),
                      [&sourceEmployee, id](const auto &obj) { return obj->getID() == id; });
    auto index = std::distance(sourceEmployee.begin(), it);

        switch(sourceEmployee[index]->getStatus()) { // returning status

            case Intern::Status::Intern: // does it recognize object properly?

                auto tmp0 = std::move(*it);
                (*it).reset();                         // ??
                *it = std::make_shared<Worker>(tmp0);

                cout << "Employee " << id << " has been promoted" << endl;
                break;
```

Comment: It seems to me that if you have an object type for each status and, in addition, store the relevant status within each object type you are duplicating information. When you duplicate ways to identify something you introduce the possibility they can get out of sync.

Comment: @Galik I just want something to distinguish the objects. I thought It's better to use `enum class` instead of just putting field i.e `std::string status = "Intern"` because enum is faster. 
When it comes to pointers, how should I replace objects?

Comment: Are you sure you are solving the right problem? It looks like all employees should be represented by the employee class directly, which just holds the right information.

Comment: Getting better. Now there is a declaration of `it`. Next: a declaration of `sourceEmployee` (or changing "Firm" to "sourceEmployee"). Plus something to consider: looking up by ID would be faster if you used a `std::map` from ID to employee instead of a `vector` of employees.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see in your example. The only difference between `Employee` and its derived classes is that the derived classes each have a `Status` field. This field serves the same purpose in all derived classes.
**Question:** Why have derived classes? Just make `status` part of `Employee` and assign it the appropriate value as employees are promoted and demoted. Then the answer to your question is that you simply assign `status` a new value (presumably through a class method).

Maybe you omitted key details. Maybe there are other fields, so there is a reason to have derived classes.
**Question** if `status` is going to be the same for all objects of a class, why is it not a `static const`? (Even then, it feels like data duplication. There may be a better way to accomplish your goal.)

If you want to transform one derived class into another, you probably want to define a constructor for each derived class that takes a reference to the base class as a parameter. This would invoke the copy constructor on the base class, then initialize the fields of the new class. (If there are fields to copy not in the base class, you've got your data organized badly.)

```
Worker::Worker(const Employee & person) : Employee(person) {}
```

As for invoking this, it looks like you have unnecessary bookkeeping going on, which could lead to errors. Tough to say, though, since your code is incomplete. Taking a guess as to the surrounding context, something like the following might work:

```
it->reset(std::make_shared<Worker>(**it));
```

Of course, whether or not this syntax is correct depends on how `it` was declared, and on how `it` was assigned a value (neither of which appear in the question).

---

Now let's move on to improving your data organization. You might find that instead of deriving from `Employee`, it would be better to have a `Job` class from which `Intern`, `Worker`, and `Manager` derive. Then `Employee` could have a (smart) pointer to `Job`, where your job-related data would reside. As a benefit, there is no copying required when switching jobs; just delete the old `Job` object and allocate a new one.
(This can be seen as a generalization of the first case I mentioned where `status` is simply assigned a new value.)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code in question."it" is looking for specified employee, `            auto it = std::find_if(sourceEmployee.begin(), sourceEmployee.end(),
                              [&sourceEmployee, id](const auto &obj) { return obj->getID() == id; });` Yes, I want every class derive from `Employee` (will add some exclusive fields for them later). I want to recognize every class in `switch()` and I thought declaring `enum class` would be good (what's the better way?).

Comment: @Taknie a better way is to not recognize every class in a `switch`. If your code needs to know which derived class you're dealing with, you're doing something wrong. Tell the class what to do via virtual methods. Think about your solution with an object-oriented mindset, not a micro-management mindset.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using virtual method to check which derived class I'm dealing with. You said that it's wrong. How Am I supposed to control which object I want to operate with. I've removed `enum` and replaced with simple `static const int` to just distinguish object by their unique number. Back to my question, I still didn't find a solution how to replace object. I created a copy constructor as you suggested but here I'm stuck. `it->reset(std::make_shared<Worker>(**it));` syntax doesn't work (no matching function to call)

Comment: @Taknie You should not use a virtual method to check which derived class you are dealing with. You should use a virtual method and not worry about which derived class you are dealing with. In the place where you *call* the virtual function, the code should not be based on which derived class you are dealing with.

Comment: Okay I get it. I would use `dynamic_cast` on `it` instead